# How to send HTML page from C web-server to web-browser

Tags: c, http, tcp, server

I have implemented basic web-server in C language, that serves GET requests from clients. The problem is that it doesn't send HTML pages.

```
while(1){
        if((temp_sock[id] = accept(sockfd, (t_sockaddr*)address, &address_size))==-1){
            perror("Accepting Failure: ");
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            fprintf(logfile, "Accepting error: %d\n", localfd);
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
            exit(1);
        }
        else{
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            fprintf(logfile, "\nAccepting Success");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }

        if (temp_sock[id]> 0){
            pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
            fprintf(logfile, "\nClient is connected");
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        }

        recv(temp_sock[id] , buf, buffsize, 0);

        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        fprintf(logfile, "\nyou recieved : %s\n ", buf);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);

        if((resource=analyze(buf))==NULL){ /*analyze - implements basic security and searches files on a disc*/
            printf("\nres is NULL");
            write(temp_sock[id], "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
            write(temp_sock[id], "Content-length: 50\n", 19);
            write(temp_sock[id], "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
            write(temp_sock[id], "<html><body><H1>404 Not Found</H1></body></html>", 50); 
        }
        else{
            while(fgets(message, 150, resource)!=NULL){
                write(temp_sock[id], "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
                write(temp_sock[id], "Content-length: 151\n", 19);
                write(temp_sock[id], "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
                write(temp_sock[id], message, 151); //here problems start
            }
        fclose(resource);
        }
        close(temp_sock[id]);
    }
}
```

This is just accepting loop of a thread, i dont post the whole code, because everything works fine up to the point when i want to send page which contains more than one line of text(e.g. wikipedia article) after it tries to read the file web-server just stops. But if file contains only

```
<html><body><H1>Hello! How are you?</H1></body></html>
```

server sends it in a proper way.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your code, but the most serious issues are here:

```
while(fgets(message, 150, resource)!=NULL){
    write(temp_sock[id], "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
    write(temp_sock[id], "Content-length: 151\n", 19);
    write(temp_sock[id], "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
    write(temp_sock[id], message, 151); //here problems start
}
```

1. `fgets()` only works properly on strings. It will behave incorrectly when reading binary data, like images. Use `fread()` instead; you will need to reorder the arguments a bit.
2. Response lines in HTTP must be terminated by `\r\n`, not just `\n`. (This isn't causing your problem, but you should fix it anyway.)
3. The Content-Length of 151 that you're sending is bogus. Either check the real size of the file (e.g, using `fstat()`) and send that, or don't send a Content-Length at all. It's not mandatory.
4. Your code is writing more bytes than it reads. Save the return value from `fgets()` and pass that to `write()`.
5. Your code isn't checking the return value from `write()`. It is not safe to assume that `write()` will always write all the data you provided to it -- just like `read()`, it may perform a partial write, or fail entirely.
6. Your code is sending a new set of HTTP headers for every block of data it reads. Move that code outside the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but what if i have a page with an article inside, containing around 500 lines, should i allocate and then send everything at once or devide it into parts?

Comment: @TeamBeam That's up to you. If you do decide to split it into multiple writes, though, use a larger buffer size -- more on the order of 64 KB, not 150 bytes.

Comment: @TeamBeam, you tell the client the whole size of the file in the header (which you only send once), then you read and transmit the data in whatever block size makes sense for your server.  The client doesn't need to know that you read a 1MB file as 500 2KB blocks, all they see is a stream upon which 1MB arrived.

Comment: @lockcmpxchg8b oh, now i have understood, thank you and OP. The server works. The only thing i would like to add is that fgets returns a pointer  `char *fgets(char *str, int n, FILE *stream)`- declaration

Comment: @TeamBeam: you still should not be using `fgets()` at all, use `fread()` instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau yes, I changed it, and i think that was one of the most crucial points and I suggest OP to make the point about `fgets()` bold.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you send HTTP header multiple times. In addition to issues mentioned by @duskwuff , you should change your loop

```
write(temp_sock[id], "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n", 16);
write(temp_sock[id], "Content-length: 151\n", 19); ///here still is a problem mentioned above
write(temp_sock[id], "Content-Type: text/html\n\n", 25);
while((currLen=fgets(message, 150, resource))!=0){

    write(temp_sock[id], message, currLen);
}
```

Comment: That was one of the problems I mentioned. See the last bullet point.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I don't know why didn't see it before :(